# Count how many times values appear in each alternate instance in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column with [1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1...]. I want to count how many times 1 and 2 appear in each alternate instance and append them to a list. So the list will look like [4,2,3,4,..]. Is there any way of doing this with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
L= [1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})

print (df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum().value_counts(sort=False).tolist())
[4, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: My column contains [121(1), 120(2), 123(1), 109(2),....] but this code prints [85, 18, 83, 45] and df.col.unique() does show that there is only 1 and 2 in the column. What do I do?

Comment: @YashKhasgiwala - You ar data are different like `L= [1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})` ?

Comment: @YashKhasgiwala - If yes, can you change them in question?

Comment: My data is L = [121 ones, 120 twos, 123 ones, 109 twos, ...]. I converted my df column into a list using `L = df.column.values.tolist()` and then used ur code.

Comment: @YashKhasgiwala - What is expected output from ` L = [121 ones, 120 twos, 123 ones, 109 twos, ...` ? I not sure if understand.

Comment: the output expected is [121, 120, 123, 109,...]. What I mean to say is my list has 121 ones then 120 twos then 123 ones then 109 twos but I am getting [85, 18, 83, 45] as output.

Comment: @YashKhasgiwala - Hmmm, for me working correctly, so it looks like some data related problem.